# Useful ways of using Strip Silence

Tags: pro-tools, strip-silence

I was wondering if anyone here had any other useful ways they use Strip Silence in Pro Tools.

Do any of you have useful ways to use Strip Silence other than taking out dead-space or ambience?

Comment: @Ryan great idea, will have to try it. Might also try a variation on your technique, using the sibilant regions as a guide for some quick volume automation tweaking.

Comment: @James Thank you! Wanted to try and give back something to this community that has been so helpful to me. Another use for this is for the tapping and inadvertent hits of a jazz stand-up bass - you can isolate the places you don't want the spiked hits - helped my friend mix 10 hours of a live-concert tour DVD.

Comment: @Filipe No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until I watched [this avid webinar](http://designingsound.org/2010/05/avid-webinar-film-sound-design-with-pro-tools-and-icon/) I was using strip silence to create regions out of lengthy library sounds that were imported as one file (particularly footsteps) but it also works for swooshes, hits, etc. really anything with multiple performances in one file. Now I use Beat Detective for anything with an intended sync point. Same principle, but is far easier IMO.

Comment: Could you use beat detective to detect all the sibilance spots?

Comment: @Ryan- hmmmm, I would guess that Strip Silence would be better as beat detective looks for transients as slice points. That's what makes it so great for footsteps. And I don't believe it has the adjustable start and end pad which I would think is quite valuable in your example.

Comment: @Ryan - which is a great tip btw!

Answer (score 1):

I've used strip silence to save time when removing breaths and extraneous noises between words from longer form VO recordings. A couple of passes with different settings seems to work better than just one pass. That said, I usually still end up going through afterwards and tweaking the edits!

It works great if the talent doesn't breath too loudly, not so much if their breaths are up near the level of the dialogue, naturally.